# Reason for using this resistor network at I/p and O/P

Tags: buffer

I am designing a board using [CDCLVC1108](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjO1KSIs8PlAhUUeisKHbtNBT4QFjABegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fcdclvc1102&usg=AOvVaw38OL_i4IyNzJbKatgPhO_b). I referred to the [EVM](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjE7JzFs8PlAhURU30KHSj1Bs4QFjAAegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fug%2Fscau042%2Fscau042.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1tlTEi95lH3rRlu0JiFIMW) and found a resistor divider kind of Network at output and input. What might be the need for these?

Comment: if you need to match impedance with something, but TI is using mostly non-resistors there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EVMs are used by engineers evaluating a chip to connect it to their measurement equipment or prototype device. Sometimes evaluation board is not directly compatible with equipment around it, and needs modification of the circuitry for some reason, like regarding termination or bias voltages. So EVMs usually contain extra provisions of modifying the input and output circuitry with either easily changeable components, solder bridges, jumpers or DIP switches. These extra components are not needed in the final circuit.